# Osburn Matrix wood stove insert making a horrible noise

Tags: fireplace, chimney, woodstove

I just bought a brand new Osburn Matrix wood stove insert and the blower is making an awful buzzing/rattling noise and is basically unusable because it is so loud. [Here is a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H-DRFz1LQw4) I uploaded that shows it happening.

What are some things I could do to troubleshoot or fix it?

Comment: And what did customer/technical support say when from Osburn when you contacted them? This is a new product; do not void your warranty by messing with it.

Comment: I can't even get them to call me back or respond by email

Comment: FYI, if a new product is bad and the manufacturer won't honor their warranty, you can contest the charge with your credit card company.

Comment: Politely point out to Osburn that you may have to take to social media to let others know about your disappointing new product experience and lack of support. Odds are good that they'll get right back to you. "They" say there's no such thing as bad publicity, but I don't buy it. Especially not these days.

Comment: The store you purchased it from may be willing to swap it for a new one and send it back to the manager as defective; talk to them.

Comment: My suspicion is that there's something wrong about the way the flue is connected, and it's acting as a big organ pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise can virtually come from anywhere. Any loose part could vibrate and make the noise.

If you used a professional to install call them back.

If you installed it your self, read and follow the 50 pages detailed instructions.

I added it for your connivance.

[manual](https://sbiweb.blob.core.windows.net/media/4682/45929a_2022-10-06.pdf)

Comment: Could the noise possibly be coming from the burning logs maybe?